# parsing json return from http in erlang

Tags: json, erlang

I test with this code :

```
get_fee(Transaction,SourceNumber,Amount, Currency) ->
Url = lists:concat(["http://localhost/test.php","?transaction=", Transaction, "&saccount=", SourceNumber,Amount,"&currency=",Currency]),
        inets:start(),
        {Flag, Response} = http:request(get, {Url, []}, [], []),
        case Flag of
            ok ->
                { { _, ReturnCode, _ }, _, Body } = Response,

                if ReturnCode =:= 200 ->
                        {ok,{_,[{_,Code},{_,Permission},{_,Payer},{_,Payee}]}} = json:decode_string(Body),
                            case Permission of true ->
                                if Code =:= 200 ->
                                    {ok,{Code, Payer, Payee}};
                                Code =:= 204 ->
                                    {nok,{Code, not_found}};
                                true ->
                                    {nok,{Code, parameter_error}}
                                end;
                            false ->
                                {nok,{Code, parameter_error}}
                            end;
                    true->
                        {error, http_error}
                end;
            error ->
                case Response of
                    nxdomain -> {error, dns_error};
                    _ -> {error, network_error}

                end
        end.
```

the response from the http is :  `{"code":200,"permission":true,"fee_payer":0,"fee_payee":19}`

But now I like to do the same think but the return of http in this case for example is :

```
{"CIN":"08321224","Name":21}
```

so I have just CIN and Name in this case

I try to change the previous

```
get_fee(Num) ->
    Url = lists:concat(["http://localhost/GTW/Operation.php","?ACCOUNT_NUM=", Num]),




            inets:start(),
             {Flag, Response} = http:request(get, {Url, []}, [], []),
            case Flag of
                ok ->
                    { { _, ReturnCode, _ }, _, Body } = Response,
                    %% for debug
                   io:format("~p~n",[ReturnCode]),
                    if ReturnCode =:= "08321224" ->
                            {ok,{_,[{_,CIN},{_,Name}]}} = json:decode_string(Body),
                                case Name of 21 ->
                                                 io:format(CIN),
                                                 io:format(Name),
                                    if CIN =:= "08321224"->
                                        {ok,{CIN, Name}};
                                    CIN =:= 204 ->
                                        {nok,{CIN, not_found}};
                                    true ->
                                        {nok,{CIN, parameter_error}}
                                    end;
                                false ->
                                    {nok,{CIN, parameter_error}}
                                end;
                        true->
                            {error, http_error}
                    end;
                error ->
                    case Response of
                        nxdomain -> {error, dns_error};
                        _ -> {error, network_error}
                    %% for debug
                    %%io:format("pass2~n ~p~n",[Response]),
                    end
  end.
```

but it displys :

```
test:get_fee("0001").
200
{error,http_error}
```

Comment: What is the question? This is Q&A site, not "we help you find bugs" site.

Comment: Also, that code could really need some idiomatic Erlang. If you reask the question in the right phrasing I'll try to help unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: The first erlang function works when I  return four values ​​in json format {"code": 200, "permission": true, "fee_payer": 0, "fee_payee": 19} from http request

Comment: Now  I have a http request that return only two  values {"CIN": "08321224", "Name": 21} in json format

so I want to develop an erlang function that work with this type of return ( with only two values of http request)

I want to inspire of the previous function ( from the first function which work with four valurs of return from http request)
My question is: how can we change the code of the erlang function get_fee in order to work with my new http request( with my new concept)

Comment: Are you using any Erlang JSON Parser library ? if so, which one are u using ? i suggest that in your questions, you simply show us the JSON sample data, and then we show you how you can parse it. Just display the JSON as it appears, then we will get a library and parse that data, so you can do the same in your code.

Comment: as you see I have in my code :  {ok,{_,[{_,Code},{_,Permission},{_,Payer},{_,Payee}]}} = json:decode_string(Body), in my file json.erl I have yhis function :
decode_string(CharList) ->
    {done, V, _} = decode([], CharList ++ eof),
    V.

Answer (score 7):

So I'll nitpick on the style here, because you will be far better off if you follow the semantical idea of Erlang:

```
get_fee(Num) ->
    Url = lists:concat(["http://localhost/GTW/Operation.php","?ACCOUNT_NUM=", Num]),
    inets:start(),
```

This is the wrong place to start `inets`. It should be started outside this function as you only need to
do this one.

```
{Flag, Response} = http:request(get, {Url, []}, [], []),
```

This part is better coded with a *pattern match*. The discrimination of `Flag` and `Response` can
be decoded directly with a simple match. Write,

```
case http:request(get, {Url, []}, [], []) of
  {ok, {{_, 200, _}, _, Body}} ->
      {ok, R} = json:decode_string(Body),
      get_fee_decode_(get_cin(R), get_name(R));
  {error, Reason} -> {error, Reason}
end.
```

I would recommend against changing `{error, nxdomain}` to `{error, dns_error}` since `nxdomain` perfectly
codes this case in any case. Just pass the error tuple to the caller and have him handle it.

```
get_fee_decode_("08321224" = CIN, 21 = Name) -> {ok, {CIN, Name}};
get_fee_decode_("204" = CIN, 21) -> {nok, {CIN, not_found}};
get_fee_decode_(CIN, _Name) -> {nok, {CIN, parameter_error}};
```

Introduce a new function like this to handle the inner parts of your code base. And hoist the matching to
top-level. This helps in the long run by decoupling your code into functions.

Do note that in a JSON structure, there is no order on an "object" so you can't assume that the structure is

```
{"code":200,"permission":true,"fee_payer":0,"fee_payee":19}
```

But a decode does not have to preserve this structure, according to JSON. So a valid decode may be:

```
[{"fee_payee", 19}, {"fee_payer", 0}, {"permission", true}, {"code", 200}]
```

This will fail to match in your code and you are setting yourself up for some nasty errors later on.

You want something along the lines of:

```
get_fee_payer(PL) -> proplists:get_value("fee_payer", PL).
```

Another thing which will be a problem with your programming style is that you are hiding error-information cases. In Erlang, you can often get away with only handling the "happy path" through the code and leave all the error handling out until you know what kind of errors are there in the code base. Then you can begin adding in error handling slowly. Defensive programming is not a thing you should be doing if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You changed:

```
if ReturnCode =:= 200 ->
```

to:

```
if ReturnCode =:= "08321224" ->
```

However, that needs to stay the same in your version.  200 is the HTTP status code for "OK" - the first step here is to verify that the server actually processed the request and returned a positive reply.  You'll find that number only in `Body` - that is what the `if CIN =:= "08321224"->` part is for.